# Multiple binlogs in /var/lib/mysql folder

Tags: server, mysql, storage

Recently I did a website and server migration. It was working fine in the beginning, but recently I found that server has consumed 100% of the storage and there are multiple bin files in `/var/lib/mysql` directory:

```
binlog.000418
binlog.000591
binlog.000328
binlog.000264
.......
```

The size it consumed is almost `30GB`.

Can some help me understand the root cause of this issue and finding a solution for this?

Comment: So what do these logs say and also what are the timestamps on these logs? What date is the oldest file, newest file, and what is the time frequency of file creation. For example, a new file each day, every hour, etc.? Also, do you have something eating up your logs (something spamming your logs)? Additionally, how long would you like to keep your logs for? For example, you can have your logs automatically delete after a certain time or size.

Comment: Use the `mysqlbinlog` command to [read these files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html).

Answer (score 0):

#### What are the binlogs?

Quote from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/binary-log.html

> The binary log contains "events" that describe database changes such
> as table creation operations or changes to table data. It also
> contains events for statements that potentially could have made
> changes (for example, a DELETE which matched no rows), unless
> row-based logging is used. The binary log also contains information
> about how long each statement took that updated data. The binary log
> has two important purposes:
>
> - For replication, the binary log on a replication source server provides a record of the data changes to be sent to replicas. The
>   source sends the information contained in its binary log to its
>   replicas, which reproduce those transactions to make the same data
>   changes that were made on the source. See Section 17.2, “Replication
>   Implementation”.
> - Certain data recovery operations require use of the binary log. After a backup has been restored, the events in the binary log that
>   were recorded after the backup was made are re-executed. These events
>   bring databases up to date from the point of the backup. See Section
>   7.5, “Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery”.

#### Delete old binlogs:

To delete old binlogs you can use [`PURGE BINARY LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/purge-binary-logs.html) statement. Open `mysql` and run this(replace the date with the one you need):

```
PURGE BINARY LOGS BEFORE '2023-11-17 08:00:00';
```

#### Disable binlog:

Open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and add these lines at the bottom of the file:

```
[mysqld]
skip-log-bin
```

Don't forget to restart the MySQL service:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

#### Limit binlog size:

Open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and add these lines at the bottom of the file:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 86400  # 1 day
max_binlog_size = 104857600         # 100M
```

Don't forget to restart the MySQL service:

```
sudo service mysql restart
```